# Send boolean value from register to login but toast is not working

Tags: java, android, android-intent, toast

I am registering the user with the right credentials, once register is complete it right away goes to login activity. I want only a toast message to be displayed when coming after a successful registration. but I am not sure what I am doing wrong here is it putting the extra or getting boolean extra? or my logic is used wrong here. In order for login to be successful, it needs to be verified using firebase, but I need a toast message to be displayed so the user knows.

**This is my RegisterActivity.class**

```
public void register(final String username, final String phoneNo, String email, String password) {
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                .addOnCompleteListener(RegisterActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            FirebaseUser firebaseUser = auth.getCurrentUser();
                            assert firebaseUser != null;
                            final String userID = firebaseUser.getUid();

                            firebaseUser.sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You have registered successfully!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                        reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(userID);

                                        HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                                        map.put("id", userID);
                                        map.put("username", username.toLowerCase());
                                        map.put("phoneNo", phoneNo);
                                        map.put("onlineStatus", "online"); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)
                                        map.put("typingTo", "noOne"); //will add later (e.g. edit profile)
                                        map.put("imageurl", "gs://araba-92732.appspot.com/placeholder.png");
                                        map.put("about", "");

                                        reference.setValue(map).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                            @Override
                                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                                                    pd.dismiss();
//The problem resides here
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                                                    intent.putExtra("isRegister", false);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    auth.signOut();
                                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_left, R.anim.slide_out_right);
                                                }
                                            }
                                        });
                                    } else {
                                        pd.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, Objects.requireNonNull(task.getException()).getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }

                                }
                            });

                        } else {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this, "You can't register with this email or password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

**This is my LoginActivity.class**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        email = findViewById(R.id.email);
        password = findViewById(R.id.password);
        login = findViewById(R.id.login);
        txt_signup = findViewById(R.id.txt_signup);
        RecoverPassword = findViewById(R.id.recoverPassTv);

///The problem resides here
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean registers = intent.getBooleanExtra("isRegister", false);
        if(!registers)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "You need to verify your email address before signing in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



        txt_signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(LoginActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);

            }
        });

        login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this);
                pd.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pd.show();

                String str_email = email.getText().toString();
                String str_password = password.getText().toString();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(str_email) || TextUtils.isEmpty(str_password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "All fields are required!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {

                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(str_email, str_password)
                            .addOnCompleteListener(LoginActivity.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                        if (Objects.requireNonNull(auth.getCurrentUser()).isEmailVerified()) {
                                            DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                                                    .child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                                            reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                                    pd.dismiss();
                                                    Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                                                    startActivity(intent);
                                                    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                                                    finish();
                                                }

                                                @Override
                                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                                    pd.dismiss();
                                                }
                                            });
                                        } else {
                                            pd.dismiss();
                                            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Please, verify your e-mail address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                        }

                                    } else {
                                        pd.dismiss();
                                        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                }
            }
        });

        RecoverPassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showRecoverPasswordDialog();
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: Are you testing on emulator or real device?

Comment: emulator, should i try with device?

Comment: sometimes toasts don't show on emulators. Either try with a real device or if not available try: snackbar or simple logs

Comment: thank you dear sir for this I am deleting the question since it is useless or keep it?

Comment: It is working now

Comment: Actually it is not useless; however, since you already accept an answer that did not solve the problem, please ask the person who answered to mention the real solution or else someone people might scroll straight to the answer without looking at the comments

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used this

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    boolean registers = getIntent().getExtras().getBoolean("isRegister");
    if(!registers)
    {
        Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "You need to verify your email address before signing 
        in!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

Comment: it works both ways so I am gonna check this answer as right, I just needed to try on device emulators as Miriana Itani said thanks!